# How to translate an SQL statement to TypeORM query builder?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, typescript, typeorm

How would I convert the code below to TypeORM querybuilder?
I am trying to follow the [documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#inner-and-left-joins).

```
this.repository.manager.query(`
    SELECT item.name, item.id
    FROM item_location
    INNER JOIN item ON item.id = item_location.itemId
    WHERE item_location.locationId = ${queryObject.filter};
`)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
await getManager()
    .createQueryBuilder(Item, 'item')
    .select(['item.id', 'item.name'])
    .innerJoin('item.location', 'location')
    .where('location.id = :id', { id: queryObject.filter });
```

Comment: what is Item? I assume its a class but that alone doesn't work. Can you update with the Item type definition?

Comment: is there any online tool to convert this easily?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if below is what you are looking for.

```
const item = await getManager().createQueryBuilder(Item, "item").innerJoinAndSelect("item.item_location", "item_location", "item_location.locationId = :queryfilter", { queryfilter: queryObject.filter}).select("item.name, item.id").getMany();
```

Comment: That code is also throwing an error.
Relation with property path item_location in entity was not found.

item_location is a table, not a property. The table has locationId and itemId properties